# Excel - compare two columns, if match subtract values of other two columns from matching rows

Tags: excel

I'm trying to compare two columns for identical values in cells. Not all of them match. For those that match, i.e. cell in col B1 matches a cell in col D2, I would like to subtract A1-C2. A and B come from one pool of data, and C and D from another. They should be compared, and values subtracted if the strings match.

[image: Image of columns]

Thank you

Comment: How do you want the results to be display? I'm guessing a list of the matching strings in one column with the corresponding result in the column to the right of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of matching strings then use this formula.  I put it in F1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$500,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$500)/(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$500,$D$1:$D$500)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

And copy down as far as you wish.  This formula only works if you have 2010 or later.

If you have 2007 or earlier than replace it with this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$500,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$500,$D$1:$D$500),ROW($1:$500)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

You will need to confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.

Then in G1 I put:

```
=IF(F1<>"",SUMIF(B:B,F1,A:A)-SUMIF(D:D,F1,C:C),"")
```

And copied down the same number of rows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, but it looks like the string is hard coded and that is not usable in this case. The formula should find the latching values and do the calculation IF it matches. Also, I just realized that the value of String should be returned so we know which string the result belongs to. :/

Comment: Thanks for helping! I do the same and I get empty cells. No errors, nothing. I just changed the range and it's in different cells in my case:

=IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$600,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$600)/(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$600,$D$1:$D$600)),ROW(1:1))),"")

=IF(I1<>"",SUMIF(B:B,I1,A:A)-SUMIF(D:D,I1,C:C),"")

Comment: @WebMast2015 What excel are you using?

Comment: @WebMast2015 the AGREGATE() Function is new in Excel 2010.  I added a formula for 2007 or earlier.

Comment: 2007 it is. Thank you very much! It looks like working correctly now... :)

Comment: @WebMast2015 please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.  It will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on following formula. It may help you.
 Formula in `E1` cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$4,0)),INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$4,0))-C1,"")
```

[image]

***Edited after comment.***
In case of table with header, use following formula: Its included `negative value` which is missing (As my assume)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([Data4],[Data2],0)),INDIRECT("B"&(MATCH([Data4],[Data2],0)+ROW($B$3)))-[Data3],[Data3]*(-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works as presented except that it breaks when used in a table with headers (A values get messed up I guess). In addition, how to make it show the values for those that do not match? These would basically be negative C values (for example we have String-88 in C column but not in B. There is always more data rows in C & D than in A & B). Thanks again!

Comment: Without table use this formula included negative value `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$4,0)),INDIRECT("A"&(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$4,0)))-C1,C1*-1)` You have to little adjust if data do not start from first row.

Comment: See edited answer for table with headers. In case of your table position in sheet, you need to adjust first column in indirect formula `Indirect("B"&...)` You have to also adjust `+ROW($B$3)` after `match` formula in `indirect` function.

Comment: Thank you. The one for without headers gives an error and highlights the last C1. The other one also gives an error and highlights the first header in the formula (your Data4, another name in my case). For the second issue, should headers be marked specifically, it is not a drop down in my table but simple text?

Comment: I share a screenshot which show correct result. Can you please share a sample file with exact structure and position of your data?