# Excel 2010: Compare two columns (A and C), find exact match string then subtract their values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data as below where I need to compare two columns (A and C), find exact match in column A and C "string" then subtract their values - for example subtract column (B - D) and put result in column E.

```
A         B       C         D           E
String1   500    String1    300
String2   1000   String1    400
String3   1500   String1    600
                 String2    750
                 String2    845
                 String2    1350
                 String3    1200
                 String3    1400
                 String3    1700 
                 String1    1775
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - compare two columns, if match subtract values of other two columns from matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249151/excel-compare-two-columns-if-match-subtract-values-of-other-two-columns-from)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this one but only difference is continuing subtraction need to apply in my case. How do I apply continuing subtraction of values (e.g. B1 - D2, B1 - D2, B1 - D3, etc.) when it matches the relevant string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in E1:

```
=SUMIF($C$1:$C$10,A1,$D$1:$D$10)-B1
```

or

```
=B1-SUMIF($C$1:$C$10,A1,$D$1:$D$10)
```

B1 is the number next to first string
A1 is the first string
Sumif will sum column D if in C string= A1
change C1:C10 and D1:D10 to correspond the last row in your Data and keep $ for fixed references.
and drag the formula down till the end of column A

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated for prompt response. I will try it.